# Unit testing euler-to-quaternion implementation fails

Tags: c++, unit-testing, quaternions, euler-angles

I'm currently trying to implement a quaternion, in which I need euler-to-quaternion conversion. My current implementation looks like this, which I've nicked from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles)

```
void Quaternion::FromEuler(double x, double y, double z)
{
    z *= Math::DegToRad;
    y *= Math::DegToRad;
    x *= Math::DegToRad;

    double xCos = Math::Cos(x / 2);
    double xSin = Math::Sin(x / 2);
    double yCos = Math::Cos(y / 2);
    double ySin = Math::Sin(y / 2);
    double zCos = Math::Cos(z / 2);
    double zSin = Math::Sin(z / 2);

    W = zCos * yCos * xCos + zSin * ySin * xSin;
    X = zCos * yCos * xSin - zSin * ySin * xCos;
    Y = zSin * yCos * xSin + zCos * ySin * xCos;
    Z = zSin * yCos * xCos - zCos * ySin * xSin;
}
```

I'm testing the implementation using the following unit test

```
TEST(Quaternions, FromEuler)
{
    Quaternion quaternion(45, 90, 180);


    ExpectNear(quaternion, 0.6532815, -0.2705981, 0.6532815, 0.270598);
}
```

Which fails in the following way.

```
  Expected | Actual     
X  0.6533   -0.6533
Y -0.2706    0.2706
Z  0.6533    0.6533
W  0.2706    0.2706
```

The expected value have been acquired from a variety of websites, which yields the same values, but with different signs, similar to how my current output differs from the expected output.

I've also tried several different implementation, yielding the same type of failure.

Is this due to rotations having [several representations](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9rLLz1XQKmaUHhmMExJbVZtb0U/view), in which case the failure of my unit test is actually a false negative? If so, how do I implement a proper unit test?

Comment: What's this `Math::` namespace ? What library is this ?

Comment: It's mine, function calls are just wrappers of the standard library. DegToRad is implemented as M_PI / 180.0

Comment: Can't exactly [reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KzdZSyD8JDSAsUyr), it's unclear how the variables in your code are related to the variables in the linked Wikipedia page. How is `Quaternion` defined in your code?

Comment: I've changed the order of the parameters in my implementation so it's (X, Y, Z) instead of the order wikipedia has of (Z, Y, X) - If you account for this in your main function it'll output the same.

Here's the full Quaternion implementation. Bit long to add to the OP.
https://hastebin.com/zoxojokiyi.cpp

Comment: Your problem appears to be mixing a generic `X,Y,Z` designation where [Conversion between quaternions and Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles) is generally described in terms of `yaw, pitch, roll` and your choice of [Axes Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axes_conventions) matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simple math it can be deduced that your expection on the results is wrong: z_deg == 180, that is z_rad == PI, will give a `zCos` value of 0.0: cos of PI/2 is 0.0.  Knowing this, you can simplify the computations of `W`,`X`,`Y`,`Z`, ignoring all products with `zCos`.

Since also x/2 and y/2 are in the first quadrant, all values for `xCos`, `xSin`, `yCos`, `ySin` and `zSin` are positive.  Therefore, the result for `X` must be negative (0.0 minus some positive product).  And, the result for `Y` must be positive: some positive product plus 0.0.

This just follows from your code and the arguments given.  The conclusion is, that either the expectations are wrong, or you have found a bug in your algorithm.  At least (as was to be expected) the actual results are plausible :-)

So, check your code and the expectations, maybe you have mixed implementation and expectations from different sources?  Or, if they came from the same source and you have not made any copying mistakes, the original author made some calculation error...

Comment: You and David both hit the nail on the head. I was incorrectly converting yaw, pitch, and roll with x, y, and z coordinates.

I have found some inconsistencies when comparing with Unity's quaternions, though. The issue posted in my original post has been fixed, so I'll post a new question for this other issue. Thanks for helping! :)